# jQuery modal dialog causes IE scrollbars to appear

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, modal-dialog

When we display a jQuery modal dialog in IE8, the parent window area shows vertical and horizontal scrollbars - how can you avoid this?

Comment: Post some code and people could probably help you alot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the content areas below the div with the scrollbars is not greater than 100% of that divs height or width at runtime.  Also, set `.wrapper {overflow: hidden;}` to hide any overrun.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem a little while ago (with a slightly different scenario):

I am using the jQuery dialog as a multi-purpose dialog with buttons that toggle the content displayed between 2 different views (info & a related form). In a helper method, I toggle the initial visibility between both elements:

```
    $("#element1").attr("style","display: block;");
    $("#element2").attr("style","display: block;");

    $("#element1").attr("style","display: none;");
    $("#element2").attr("style","display: none;");
```

Then, within the conditional block I set the height of the modal to that of element to be displayed + 50px (to account for the custom set of buttons I have created), like so:

```
    var elementHeight = $("#element1").height();
    $("#dialog1").dialog("option", "height", elementHeight + 50);
```

Once I resize the dialog's div element, I set the final state for the dialog's content:

```
    $("#element1").attr("style","display: block;");
    $("#element2").attr("style","display: none;");
```

I know this is a bit of a hack. There are probably more "elegant" ways to resolve this issue, but I didn't want to burn any more time on it (I just spent about 3 hours wrestling with this issue, trying different tweaks to the core jQuery code).

If anyone comes up with a better way to resolve this, I am all ears (err, eyes?), but until then this is working for me.